# Querystring in C# web application

Tags: asp.net

I have created web application.I am giving one of web page to client as api.Client can pass parameter to web page like below

```
Ex: www.domainname.com/Testpage.aspx?name=pinky&city=pune&number=xxxxxxxx
```

In same page Testpage.aspx,I am accessing/fetching querystring like below.

```
string s= Request.Querystring["name"];
```

I am not sure how client can call api.I mean to say from browser or code throught.Whether client use urlencode or not?

from code

```
www.domainname.com/Testpage.aspx?name=Server.UrlEncode("pinky")&city=Server.UrlEncode("pune")&number=Server.UrlEncode("xxxxxxxx")
```

will below code work ? or does i need to decode?If client did not use Encode then decode work fine?.I want user querystring value further processing and insert into table.

string s= Request.Querystring["name"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not decode it. If they have entered special characters and not encoded then it will not reach your server-side code at all because it will throw a bad request error. If they have encoded at their end then it will be automatically decoded at your end.

Even If they have not encoded, Your decode will work fine.

Comment: Hi Anoop H.N,thanks for ur reply.Client call my url and pass value.I am fetching it using request object.

Comment: In that case, You need not decode it. Because, If they have entered special characters and not encoded then it will not reach your server-side code at all. If they have encoded at their end then it will be automatically decoded at your end.